# sub sequence of coin tosses

Tags: probability

Each of two players picks a different sequence of two coin tosses.  That is, each player gets to pick among HH, HT, TH, and TT.  Then, a coin is flipped repeatedly and the first player to see his sequence appear wins.  For example, if one player picks HH, the other picks TT, and the coin produces a sequence that starts H, T, H, T, T, then the player who picked TT wins.  The coin is biased, with H having a 2/3 probability and T having a 1/3 probability.  If you played this game, would you want to pick your sequence first or second?

Answer (score 2):

Second.

1. First player choose HH, second player chose TH ($\frac{5}{9}$ of win)
2. First player choose HT, second player chose HH ($\frac{2}{3}$ of win)
3. First player choose TH, second player chose HT ($\frac{2}{3}$ of win)
4. First player choose TT, second player chose HT ($\frac{8}{9}$ of win)

But if I was forced to play first, I will chose HH against a good opponent, and TH against a "not knowing" opponent (that could be lured by HH).

Answer (score 1):

Second. The first player will pick HH, anything else is worse. I pick TH, and win unless the first two tosses are HH. So I win with probability $\frac{5}{9}$.

**Remark:** Although it is obvious that the first player is best off picking HH, for a complete solution you need to specify your response for each of the $4$ possible choices of the first player.